# I have a PopupBox that I want to change the icon for. Currently it defaults to DotsVertical and I would like to have it as a DotsHorizontal

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I am using MaterialDesignInXAML for a WPF application.  I have a PopupBox that I want to change the icon for.  Currently it defaults to `DotsVertical` and I would like to have it as a `DotsHorizontal`.

I tried the following with no luck.

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" StaysOpen="False">
    <materialDesign:PopupBox.Content>
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="DotsHorizontal" />
    </materialDesign:PopupBox.Content>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Test1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test2" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test3" />
    </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured it out and will leave an answer here in case anyone else comes across this issue.  There is a property called `ToggleContent`

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" StaysOpen="False">
    <materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="DotsHorizontal" />
    </materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Test1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test2" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test3" />
    </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to change the Icon and preserve the current style use this:

```html
<materialDesign:PopupBox PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" StaysOpen="False">
     <materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
         <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="DotsHorizontal" 
                                Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=materialDesign:PopupBox}, Path=Foreground}"                        />
         </materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Test1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test2" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test3" />
    </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```